# How to load uint8_t *src to uint16x8_t

Tags: arm, neon, intrinsics

How to load uint8_t *src to uint16x8_t?
For example, we can only do the following:

```
uint8_t *src;
```

--->

```
uint8x8_t mysrc = vld1_u8(src);
```

Seems that I can not use vreinterpret_*() or (uint16x8_t)mysrc to transform mysrc to uint16x8_t? Is it right?

Comment: A clear case for vmovl. It's such a trivial thing if you know assembly. You won't get very far with intrinsics unless you learn the instructions themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the 8 first values as 8-bit values:

```
uint8x8_t mysrc8x8 = vld1_u8(src);
```

Then use the ["convert long move"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/BABGABJH.html) instruction to transform these values to 16-bit values by prepending zeroes in the first 8 bits:

```
uint16x8_t mysrc16x8 = vmovl_u8(mysrc8x8);
```

Assuming that after some operations on these values, you obtain your output `myoutput16x8` in an `uint16x8_t` format and want to convert them back to `uint8x8_t`, then you can use the `vmovn_u16` instruction, bearing in mind that it will indeed **truncate** the values if they are bigger than 255:

```
uint8x8_t myoutput8x8 = vmovn_u16(myoutput16x8);
```

Hope this helps!